# JNDI lookup failure

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, jndi, jbossts

i would be grateful if someone can help me rectify the issue in my code. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Currently my persistence.xml contains

```
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="#####.hibernate.JbossTSTransactionManagerLookup"/>

  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="jta"/>
```

along with

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="####"/>

    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>

</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">

    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:comp/env/TransactionManager"/>

</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Context initialization failed : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [###XMLConfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: JTA TransactionManager is not available at JNDI location [java:comp/env/TransactionManager]; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple] available at JNDI location [java:comp/env/TransactionManager] is not assignable to [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]

Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: JTA TransactionManager is not available at JNDI location [java:comp/env/TransactionManager]; nested exception is org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple] available at JNDI location [java:comp/env/TransactionManager] is not assignable to [javax.transaction.TransactionManager]

at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.lookupTransactionManager(JtaTransactionManager.java:598)

Caused by: org.springframework.jndi.TypeMismatchNamingException: Object of type [class com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionManagerImple] available at JNDI location [java:comp/env/TransactionManager] is not assignable to [javax.transaction.TransactionManager] at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup()
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.lookupTransactionManager()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is some issue with the classpath of your project. Check if there are two versions of the same dependency in your project. In my case I had multiple versions of the jboss-transaction jar in the classpath, keeping just one version of it fixed the issue for me. Check if there is any transitive dependency which is causing this issue which you can exclude in your maven pom.

Comment: in my case don't have two versions, in pom only one postgre sql dependency added but still getting same issue